# JQuery TreeView Plug-in SelectedItem Highlighting

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the JQuery TreeView plug-in and I would like a know how I can highlight/identify the last selected node.  Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I did not receive an answer to my questions from Alexander Corotchi, I ended up implementing my own solution to the problem.  I'm sure there are simpler solutions out there, but here it is.

```
 $(treeView).treeview({
        /* Initialize TreeView */
    }) 
 $(treeView).click(function onTreeViewClick(sender) {
        var clickedElement = $(sender.target);
        if (clickedElement.hasClass('hover')) {
            //Find all selected nodes and deselect them.
            var treeView = $(document.getElementById('usxTreeView'));
            $.each(treeView.find(".selectedNode"), function(index, node) {
                $(node).removeClass('selectedNode');
            });
            //Select newly selected node
            clickedElement.addClass('selectedNode');
            //Get the node Id for the parent LI
            var parents = clickedElement.parent('li');               
            //This can then be used to identify the node.
            selectedTreeNodeId = parents[0].id; 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul.yourclassselected li:last-child').addClass( 'highlight class' );
```

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to JQuery.  Where do I put this line?  in the document ready?  What do yourclassselected and highlighted class represent?

Comment: Also, I am using the async treeview (lazy loading).  Would this be a game changer?  Sorry I should have mentionned that.

Comment: I would also like to identify the node.  Set a javascript variable with its ID